# forget password code in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the code for forget password written in php. But it is not working. whenever I execute it it shows that the mail has been sent to particular email. But no mail is sent.
Here's the code

```
<?php
include('./connect1.php');
$username = $_GET['user'];
$password = $_GET['pass'];
$email = "";
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $email = $row['email'];
}
else{
    echo "no such user exists";
}
$to = $email;
$from = "gopal@gmail.com";
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Password Reset</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please click on this link to reset your passowrd</p>
<a href='www.someone.com/login/reset.php?user=".$username."'>Reset Password</a>
</body>
</html>
";
$subject = "Password Reset";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <gopal@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo '<script>alert("Password reset mail has been sent to'.$email.'");</script>';
?>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Put a conditional on the `mail`. Did you also check your spam folder? This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Please do not use this code in anything besides learning how not to do it. It is insecure, manipulatable, and not good practice.

Comment: This is not secure. You need a random token as well as the username to allow the password change. Anyone could request a password change and create the reset link without recieving the email.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a configuration error. if you insist on using PHP mail function, you will have to edit php.ini.

if you are looking for an easier and more versatile option (in my opinion), you should use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: what edit do i have to make?

Comment: If you dont want to modify .ini file you may use 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'mail@yourdomain.com');